# How can I load image into picture box from another computer?

Tags: c#

I need my picture box to load image from another computer. It means a different IP address. I have tried loading image from same computer and it works. But I need to load image from a separate server PC. The code below does not work.

pbFeature.Image = Image.FromFile(@"\192.168.232.100\C:\pic\a.png");

Comment: Put C# to one side. Work out how to access that file **in Windows Explorer**. Once you can do that, the C# is trivial - copy the path over. Until then, this isn't a C# problem. This is a permissions / Windows problem.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Would you expect `Image.FromFile(@"\any-arbitrary-computer\C:\Users\unwilling-joe\my-private-data.png");` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network paths start with `\\` not `\`. Assuming the file is shared correctly you just need `pbFeature.Image = Image.FromFile(@"\\192.168.232.100\C:\pic\a.png");`

Paste that same path into windows explorer and it should open the image if it is shared correctly.

Comment: I tried to make folder accessible by another computer and tried this code. Nailed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

share the file/folder to access by another computer. then you access file like below

```
var file= File.ReadAllText(@"\\server\path\filename.png");
```

then use the file where ever you want